# How to get a child of an "object sender" in a method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a 15 borders with an image inside of it in my application that calls a method on MouseUp.. all images have different names.. hence why i want them all to call this one method

```
<GroupBox Width="75" Height="75">
      <Border MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseUp1" Background="Transparent">
           <Image x:Name="RedPick5_Image" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
      </Border>
</GroupBox>
```

I want all of them to be able to set the image source of the child (the image is the child of the border if i understand correctly.. how can i do this?

```
        private void Image_MouseUp1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //want to set any image that calls this
            //something like Sender.Child.Source = ...
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way in case image is only and immediate child of border:

```
Image image = (Image)((Border)sender).Child;
image.Source = // Set image source here.
```

Comment: it's you again!  if this works i can sleep in peace and have a good day at work tomorrow.  brb trying

Comment: you've made me so happy i'd kiss you if you were here.  i'm going to knock out.. it wont let me select you as the correct answer for another 9 minutes.  will give you credit in the morning.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 5):

you need to cast the sender and check

```
    private void Image_MouseUp1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = sender as Border; // Cast to Border
        if (border != null)            // Check if the cast was right
        {
            var img = border.Child as Image;  // Cast to Image
            if (img != null)                  // Check if the cast was right
            {
                // your code
            }
            // else your Child isn't an Image her you could hast it to an other type
        }
        // else your Sender isn't an Border
    }
```

you could also do this

```
    private void Image_MouseUp1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = sender as Border;
        if (border == null) // if the cast to Border failed
            return;         

        var img = border.Child as Image;
        if (img == null) // if the cast to Image failed
            return;

        // your code
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this.  very informative to learn different ways to answer a question

Comment: @user1189352 i wasn't finish, i will add more explanations ;)

Comment: please do!  i'm all about learning.  just have major time constraints for this project so had to resort to stackoverflow

Comment: I used to check for nulls, but is it really the right thing to do? If your sender is not what you expect, someone is calling the event from a place that shouldn't be calling. Idk, just wondering.

Comment: @BrunoLM you could throw an FormatException if the sender must always of your expected type

Comment: @WiiMaxx - So why not have strong type instead and let `TypeCastException` to be thrown automatically. Agree with BrunoLM, in case we expect child to be Image, we should not put these safety checks.

Comment: @RohitVats just in case he want to extend his code later on and to be more save again `murphy's law`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
(Image)(sender as Border).FindName("RedPick5_Image");
```

It will search `Border`'s children recursively for an element named "RedPick5_Image". This may return null if no elements with the specified name is found.